# Параллельное программирование с++,openmp

Tags: c++, openmp

Задание было, написать программу и распараллелить ее, само задание звучит так : Циклическим сдвигом строки s называется строка sksk+1sk+2…s|s|s1s2…sk-1 для некоторого k, здесь |s| - длина строки s. Подстрокой строки s называется строка sisi+1…sj-1sj для некоторых i и j. Вам даны две строки a и b. Выведите количество подстрок строки a, являющихся циклическими сдвигами строки b.

Входные данные
Первая строка входного файла INPUT.TXT содержит строку a (1 ≤ |a| ≤ 1000). Во второй строке входного файла записана строка b (1 ≤ |b| ≤ min(100,|a|)). Обе строки состоят только из символов английского алфавита и цифр.

Выходные данные
В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите целое число – ответ на задачу.
Программу я написал, но распараллелить не смог,аргументируя ,что дана последовательность, которую если разбив то можно потерять пару c, сказали,что я не прав и что можно распараллелить , подскажите как это можно реализовать

```
#include<iostream>
```

## include

## include

using namespace std;

string cs(string s) {

```
if (s.size())
    s = (s + s[0]).erase(0, 1);
return s;
```

}

int f(string s, string t) {

```
string  q;

 q = s;

int k = 0, i = 0, j;

do {
    do {
        j = t.find(s, i);
        if (j == string::npos)
            i = 0;
        else {
            k++;
            i = j + 1;
        }
    } while (i);
    s = cs(s);
} while (s != q);
return k;
```

}

int main() {

```
ifstream in("input.txt");

ofstream out("output.txt");


string t, s;


in >> t >> s;

int k ;
k = f(s,t);
cout << k;
out << k;
out.close();

return 0;
```

}

Comment: s = (s + s[0]).erase(0, 1); жесть то какая.... может для начала переписать под цикл программу?

Comment: 1. переписать на for. 2. omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());  #pragma omp parallel for и ниже цикл for

Comment: Переписал под for,но не понимаю как дальше расспараллелить , если мы будем разбивать строку,мы потеряем данные
string cs2(string s) {
 string sub_s = "";
 if (s.size()) {
  for (int i = 1; i < s.size(); i++) {
   sub_s += s[i];
  }
 }
 sub_s += s[0];
 return sub_s;
}